# Adding Gaussian Noise to unbalanced dataset

Tags: machine-learning, python, unbalanced-classes

I have a highly umbalanced dataset, and the models that I used are overfitting. I read somewhere about SMOTE and I wanted to try it. However, the latter needs at least two samples (k_neighbors=1) to perform oversampling. The minority class in my dataset has one sample, thus SMOTE won't work. To oversee this problem I want to replicate (duplicate?) the minority class and add some gaussian noise and then apply SMOTE.
So my questions are:

1. Is this approach realistic? is it ok to apply it?
2. Should I add the Gaussian noise to the features or labels or both (my dataset is already seperated to features and labels)
3. How can I choose the best parameters for the gaussian noise (sigma and mu)? should I use the following code for that?

```
import numpy as np 
mu, sigma = 0, 0.1 
# creating a noise with the same dimension as the dataset (features, labels, or both) "dim"
noise = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, "dim") 
print(noise)
```

Answer (score 2):

*Imagine that you are trying to learn a new language from a textbook. Unfortunately you were given only a single page of the textbook. This is not enough to learn much, so to generate more pages you cut the page into tiny pieces, each containing one to few letters, then shuffle them and randomly combine. Would this give you more textbook pages?*

If you don't have enough data to oversample it, than the problem is not having unbalanced data, but *not having enough data*. You cannot gain additional data by oversampling it, or adding noise to it.

Yes, to some extent, you can use things like [data augmentation](https://medium.com/@thimblot/data-augmentation-boost-your-image-dataset-with-few-lines-of-python-155c2dc1baec), but those techniques are based on meaningful transformations of the data, rather than adding noise to it. It also won't work if your initial data is not big enough.

Comment: Oww, this complicates things. What if I can't get more data?